# silverlight 4 deployment: system.web.ria is missing?

Tags: .net, silverlight, iis

This is driving me nuts, and I can't seem to find what I need.  My problem seems to be what this article addresses: http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/12/10/tips-to-deploy-ria-services-troubleshoot.aspx

Which is: I have this silverlight application, and some fancy web services, and they work Grrreat! Except when I actually come to set it up in IIS, either on my development machine, or the server.

I *believe* I've installed everything needed, but system.web.ria is not present in the global assembly cache, nor does it seem to be something I can include in my project's references.  Why this even works at all when I use visual studio's dev/debug server is a mystery to me.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Ok, so it looks like the problem is probably that we're using a library that was compiled against an older version of silverlight or something, and that System.Web.Ria is deprecated.  This is all total voodoo.

Answer (score 2):

`System.Web.Ria` doesn't exist any more. It's been replaced by the `System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server` and `System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting` namespaces.

You also need to update your web.config so it reads:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
        <system.web>
            <httpModules>
                <add name="DomainServiceModule"
type="System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHttpModule,
      System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0,
      Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
            </httpModules>
            <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" /> 
        </system.web>

        <system.webServer>
            <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
            <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
                <add name="DomainServiceModule" preCondition="managedHandler"
 type="System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHttpModule,
       System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0,
       Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
            </modules>
            <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        </system.webServer>

    <system.serviceModel>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
                                   multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

The full details can be found in the [Breaking Changes from Beta(PDC 09) to RTW](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=RiaServices&DownloadId=8313) document (docx file).

I'm not sure why this works from Visual Studio unless it still has some cached files it's using.